# A record points to new webhost but local clients still get certificate errors

Tags: domain-name-system, certificate, website, ssl-certificate-errors

Our main website was moved to a new webhost and a new domain. We control our DNS and were instructed to change the A record for olddomain.com to point it to the new host newdomain.ca.

We lowered the TTL about a week before the change and made the change on November 1st.

Since then some, not all, clients e.g. mobile and desktop of varying browsers are getting certificate errors when browsing to https://olddomain.com. If the option is available to continue anyway then you are sent to https://newdomain.ca and the correct cert shows.

We were told that this issue with with the local clients that had previously browsed to the website and are caching the old certificate for olddomain.com. Further to that the easiest thing to do would be to migrate DNS to new nameservers so that local clients would be forced to purge the old cert.

That's *almost* makes sense to me except I don't understand why the issue persists if I clear my SSL state and browser cache.

---

Why I am still getting certificate errors when browsing to https://olddomain.com? It should just be redirecting to newdomain.ca

Comment: The only viable way to diagnose this is to inspect the invalid certificate.

Comment: I guess I should have mentioned the certificate error is coming from the newdomain.com which is what should be happening but it sees it a mismatch. I don't know why the browser just isn't happy being forwarded to the correct site. If I click "Advanced" > "Go forward anyway" then the correct site newdomain.ca shows up just fine.

Comment: You need a certificate for the old domain for requests to the old domain, even if it only responds with a redirect.

Comment: That is in line with what I was thinking.. _if_ this was IIS I would host both sites with both respective certs and the old site one would redirect to the new one. When I suggested that I was told about changing DNS hosting instead. This is not a problem for _everyone_ just certain browsers. If I browse to the old site in chrome I get directed to the new site just fine with no errors. Doing the same thing in IE11 I get the cert invalid page.